# Vacuum the debris from rocks?

Tags: rocks

Can I vacuum small leaves and debris off or out of my rocks--without vacuuming up the rocks?  I don't have a rock garden yet, but I'm considering using Ginger rock, 1.5", instead of standard mulch.

Comment: Depends on the air watts of the vacuum you use - my vacuum would suck stones that size up without even pausing...

Comment: Even if it doesn't suck up the "big" rocks, it will pick up a lot of rock dust which won't do the vacuum any good in the long term.

Comment: If you use a Ship-Vac (assuming you're in the US), you may be okay for awhile. Could you fit some quarter-inch mesh over the vacuum's nozzle to prevent the rocks from going in?

Comment: How about a low power leaf blower?  Blow the leaves out and then vacuum or collect them with a rake or similar tool.

Comment: Ground cloth, or some such is nice. Weeds can be quite insistent about coming up through your measly 4" deep pebble bed.

Comment: I have the same issue, having a bunch of rocks under a pine tree so it's a constant issue and I'm SO fed up. After too much browsing on YouTube, I found someone who used a flamethrower and it seemed to work perfectly :D (don't try this at home)

Answer (score 2):

A leaf blower is probably your best bet. If the rocks are dry you should be able to blow any debris out from the cracks, while a high power enough to suck anything other than light dust out of cracks will pull your rocks with it.
If you foresee the rocks getting muddy there's not a lot you can do but replace them with clean ones...